# Border-Radius Interior Tearing in Certain Browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, tearing

Hoping someone has seen this before. I'm only hearing about this bug from two users and they're both using tablets (I can get specifics, if it matters) for their workstations (I know...). When they view a website, if a button has a border radius, they see this...

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=69f1996

(i had originally wanted to post the actual image so it wouldn't expire, but I need more reputation - if you visit this page after the link has expired, basically, it shows a green button with rounded corners and a symmetrical white "tearing" across the object, meeting in the center - think green button with white X inside)

They've reported seeing this in Internet Explorer (fully updated) and Firefox.

Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Comment: Well, people are viewing this and someone was kind enough to mark the question as a bad one without explanation (unless all questions start out at -1... which I doubt). If I missed the answer somewhere, please speak up. I have searched and found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by rolling back a display driver. There was an odd play between the up to date driver and the docks.